# set all matching elements in a multiindex dataframe to a series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Previously I have been using a `pandas.Panel` to store multiple dataframes, one per date in a list of dates.

Since the deprecation of panels, I am trying to convert to using a multindex dataframe.

As an example, I have the following data:

```
dates  = pandas.date_range('20180101', periods=3)
stocks = ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', 'FB']
```

Before the deprecation, I could create a panel as follows:

```
pnl = pandas.Panel(items=dates, major_axis=stocks, minor_axis=stocks, dtype=float)
```

I now have 1 dataframe per date, for example, selecting the first:

```
pnl['2018-01-01']
```

returns a dataframe as follows:

[image]

Now, however, as per the advice in the depracation warning, I am creating a multiindex dataframe:

```
tuples = list(itertools.product(dates, stocks))
index  = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['date', 'stock'])
df     = pandas.DataFrame(index=index, columns=stocks, dtype=float)
```

The resulting dataframe now looks like this:

[image]

So far so good...

**Populating the dataframe:**

I have a `pandas.Series` of data for a given stock pair, with one entry per date.

For example:

```
data = pandas.Series([1.3, 7.4, 8.2], index=dates)
```

The series looks like this:

```
2018-01-01    1.3
2018-01-02    7.4
2018-01-03    8.2
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Say, for example, this data is for stock pair `['GOOG','MSFT']`.

I would like to set **all** `['GOOG','MSFT']` entries.

With my panel, I could very easily do this using the following terse syntax:

```
pnl.loc[:,'GOOG','MSFT'] = data
```

What is the easiest way to select all `['GOOG','MSFT']` elements from my multiindex dataframe, and set them to my `pandas.Series` object (ie: date for date)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `pd.DataFrame.loc` & `pd.IndexSlice`:

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[data.index, 'GOOG'], 'MSFT'] = data.values
```

If you have many pairs of data, put them in a dictionary like this:

```
pairs = {('GOOG', 'MSFT'): data}
```

Then iterate through the pairs, setting the value using `loc` & `pd.IndexSlice`.

```
for k, v in pairs.items():
    df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[v.index, k[0]], k[1]] = v.values
```

As an alternative to `IndexSlice`, you can set up a boolean index on the multiindex using the index method `get_level_value`

```
df.loc[ (df.index.get_level_values(1) == 'GOOG') &
        (df.index.get_level_values(0).isin(data.index))
       , 'MSFT'] = data.values
```

All of the above would produce the following output :

```
                  AAPL  GOOG  MSFT  AMZN  FB
date       stock
2018-01-01 AAPL    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
           GOOG    NaN   NaN   1.3   NaN NaN
           MSFT    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
           AMZN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
           FB      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2018-01-02 AAPL    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
           GOOG    NaN   NaN   7.4   NaN NaN
           MSFT    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
           AMZN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
           FB      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2018-01-03 AAPL    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
           GOOG    NaN   NaN   8.2   NaN NaN
           MSFT    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
           AMZN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
           FB      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
```

Comment: `df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[data.index, 'GOOG'], 'MSFT']` gives me an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'DatetimeIndex'`

Comment: what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I am using version `'0.22.0'`

Comment: I'm on `0.23.0`, and it is working for me. Does the boolean indexing technique which I shared as an alternative work for you?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you. It seems quite verbose though, as with a panel I could do `pnl.ix[:, 'GOOG', 'MSFT']` to achieve the same effect. Are you aware of a more terse syntax to achieve this?

Comment: no, but you can easily write a function and use it for brevity: `def fltr(df, dates, logo): return (df.index.get_level_values(0).isin(dates)) & (df.index.get_level_values(1) == logo)` or upgrade your pandas version and make use of the fix `IndexSlice`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea!

Comment: please note I found `df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'GOOG'], 'MSFT']` to work, which is somewhat more terse than the `get_level_values` method

Comment: nice, just note that replacing `data.index` with `:` implies that you want to assign a value to every date in `df` and that `data` has a value for each date.